# ViewPager with page pop

Tags: android, collections, android-viewpager

I have to show a collection of train tickets to a user so I used a ViewPager, where each page contains a single ticket. This ViewPager has padding, allowing to see a small portion of the next/previous ticket, while showing the focused ticket in the middle.

But what I want to achieve is that when I pressed a ticket page, I want it to expand into "full screen" smoothly. I don't know if using a ViewPager in this case is the better solution, because I'm expanding something that is inside a fragment in a view pager, and the "expanded ticket" is another activity.

I like ViewPager because it centers the pages the way I like.

As an example of what I want to do is done [here](http://inspirationmobile.tumblr.com/post/140197819964/restaurant-app-for-android-by-bien-the-best).

A user clicks an item of the pager/collection and it expands to full screen smoothly.

What I'm asking is if anyone knows the best way to achieve this. Should I keep using a ViewPager? Should I use a RecyclerView?

Thanks in advance

João

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is shared elements for the item click
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

And the android support library may help you enhance the design like what's done on the link you provided
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: I thought about it, and I think it's the best approach. The only thing I that made me not use it right away is because I'm using fragments inside the viewPager. I'm not sure but I think the shared views are only possible between fragments or between activities, not between fragment and activities..

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the current view:

```
View view =  MyActivity.mViewPager.getFocusedChild();
```

- Set an onclick listener of that view;
- Create an AnimationSet with a ScaleAnimation;
- Finally add that AnimationSet to your view that you get using the code shown above.

You can even add/replicate the "pop" by scaling it up quickly to a size larger than you want it and then scaling down to the final size you want but with a slower animation. Set the speed by using setDuration on your ScaleAnimation.

Comment: Try implementing it and show me what you've got if you get stuck :)

Comment: That's an option, but since I'm showing a lot of stuff in the expanded view, I wanted it to be in a different activity for better management  guess. Because if each page has a complex layout, it will run very slow on older devices :/

Comment: I see. Well I guess theres only one way to find out. If you want it in an activity then just use the on touch to open a new activity and inflate that viewpager items view.

Comment: Or open it in a fragment?